# Module vs Class vs Object Literal

Tags: node.js

This is specific to nodejs.

When is it best to use a module or a class or an object literal?

A module would look like this:

```
//myModule.js
module.exports = {
    function func1() {
        console.log("func1");
    }
    function func2() {
        console.log("func2");
    }
}

//in another js file
const myModule = require('myModule');
myModule.func1();
myModule.func2();
```

The class would look something like this. We could also do this the javascript prototype way, but doing this here for simplicity.

```
//myClass.js
class myClass {
     func1() {
         console.log("Func1");
     }
     func2() {
         console.log("Func2");
     }
}

module.exports = myClass;

//in another js file
const myClass = require('myClass');

let newClass = new myClass();
newClass.func1();
newClass.func2();
```

Finally, we could have an object literal singleton.

```
//myObj.js
let myObj = {
    func1: function() {
        console.log("Func1");
    },
    func2: function() {
        console.log("Func2");
    }
};
module.exports = myObj;

//in another js file
let myObj = require('myObj');
myObj.func1();
myObj.func2();
```

The difference between the class and the object literal is that object literal acts as a singleton; whereas class could have multiple instances.

But what about the difference between an object literal and the module example. Are those exactly the same pattern?

Comment: These are many different questions rolled into one post, all of which a good (e)book or tutorial on JS in general, and Node.js specifically, cover in perfectly acceptable detail.

Comment: There's not really a difference between the first and last example.

Comment: `module.exports` is JUST a plain object, no different than any other plain object except that whatever object reference is in `module.exports` happens to be the exported interface for the module.  So, within the module where its defined, there's NO difference at all between `module.exports` and a plain object you would declare local to the module.  It's just a predefined plain object that already exists as a property of the module object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what about the difference between an object literal and the module example. Are those exactly the same pattern?

A class should be used when there's a chance of it being *used* properly as a class (for example, if you ever want to put or retrieve data on an instance, where that instance also has methods, a class makes perfect sense).

```js
// MyClass.js
class MyClass {
     func1() {
         console.log("Func1");
     }
     func2() {
         console.log("Func2");
     }
     setData(data) {
         this.data = data;
     }
     getData() {
         return this.data;
     }
}

const instance = new MyClass();
instance.setData('foo');
console.log(instance.getData());
```

But if, as this case appears to be, you only want to collect similar functions together, a class makes the code much more confusing for no real benefit. Readers of the code (which may include yourself, somewhere down the line) will expect a class to be used for *something* that a plain object can't do.

Your `myModule.js` is pretty much identical to your `myObj.js` - both are exporting a plain object which has certain properties on it. The only difference is the existence of the intermediate variable `myObj`, which isn't used aside from being an intermediate variable.

Defining the object to be exported in a standalone variable before exporting it can help a bit when you want to reliably reference other properties of the exported object:

```
// a little bit verbose, have to reference `module.exports` every time
// to get to the exported object:
module.exports = {
  getSummary() {
    // using "this" instead may not be reliable without a `bind`
    const { summary } = module.exports.getAllInfo();
    return summary;
  }
  getAllInfo() {
    // ...
  }
};
```

```
// a little bit more DRY:
const obj = {
  getSummary() {
    const { summary } = obj.getAllInfo();
    return summary;
  }
  getAllInfo() {
    // ...
  }
};
module.exports = obj;
```

You also might (or might not) consider defining the object to be exported in a standalone variable to be more readable. You can use whatever you like that suites your use-case.

Comment: Could also do `const obj = module.exports = { ... }` and use `obj` within the methods.

Comment: Yep, that's one option, though IMO it looks a bit odd and violates the [`no-multi-assign`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multi-assign) rule that I prefer

Comment: To each their own :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know there's a thousand ways to do things in JS/Node.